# Hide / Show @IBOulet @IBAction on load in Cell

Tags: ios, swift, cell

I am trying to only let the button show if the value of something is available.

```
@IBAction func instagramButtonHide(_ sender: Any) {
    if(self.thisLens.instagramURL.isEmpty){
        addInstagramButton.isHidden = true
    }else{
        let url = URL(string: thisLens.instagramURL)!
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

The code is working but only if you click on it. So I thought let's place it in the viewDidAppear so it loads when the view loads but since it is in a cell I can't do this.

So if the value of instagramURL is empty I don't want the button to show up.

I feel there is an easy fix but I can't find it.

```
@IBOutlet weak var addFacebookButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!

var thisLens: WordPressPost!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code


    addFacebookButton.isHidden = self.thisLens.facebookURL.isEmpty
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func favoriteButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

}

@IBAction func facebookButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = URL(string: thisLens.facebookURL)!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

And the other one

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var thisLens: WordPressPost!

    var numberOfPosts = posts.count
    if searchController.isActive {
        numberOfPosts = filteredPosts.count
    }
    if indexPath.row != numberOfPosts {
        var thisPost: WordPressPost
        if searchController.isActive {
            thisPost = filteredPosts[indexPath.row]
        }
        else {
             thisPost = posts[indexPath.row]
        }
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lensCell", for: indexPath) as! LensCell

        cell.thisLens = thisPost
        if thisPost.authorName == "" {
            cell.authorNameLabel.text = "No Author"
        }
        else {
            cell.authorNameLabel.text = thisPost.authorName
        }
        if thisPost.title == "" {
            cell.lensNameLabel.text = "No Title"
        }
        else {
            cell.lensNameLabel.text = thisPost.title
        }

        if thisPost.image != nil {
            cell.snapCodeImageView.image = thisPost.image
            cell.imageLoadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
        else {
            cell.snapCodeImageView.image = nil
            cell.imageLoadingIndicator.startAnimating()
            downloadImage(url: URL(string: thisPost.imageURL)!, cellIndexPath: indexPath, wasSearchControllerActive: searchController.isActive, typingUID: currentTypingUID)
        }
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "loadingCell", for: indexPath) as! LoadingCell
        cell.loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain "it is in a cell"?

Comment: @PhillipMills What i mean is that you have the Table View then the Table View Cell. The button is in the Table View Cell. That Table View Cell has it's own Class file and that's where i put the IBOutlet and IBAction for the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then do this inside `awakeFromNib` of the cell

```
addInstagramButton.isHidden = self.thisLens.instagramURL == nil
```

or inside `cellForRowAt`

```
let item = ///
cell.addInstagramButton.isHidden = item.instagramURL == nil
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I seem to get this problem now: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Is there an option to check for isEmpty and nil at the same time? B.t.w. I used the awakeFromNib option.

Comment: I have added some code from the cell, the cellforwhat doesn't include thisLens or facebookURL so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: you must assign a value to `thisLens` from `cellForRowAt` as it's nil

Comment: I have added that but still the same error... added the cellForRowAt under the other codesnippet

Comment: you need to debug inside the cell print `thisLens` or `instagramURL` and verify which is nil

Comment: It's the instagramURL that prints nil

Answer (score 0):

Code to set up a button in a cell doesn't belong in the IBAction or in `viewDidAppear()`. It belongs in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method.

You need to set up that method to fully configure the cell.

You should create a custom cell class, set up a template in your storyboard, and wire up outlets to the custom cell class in the template. Then when you dequeue a cell, cast it to the custom type and set the cell's button's hidden state as appropriate.

Fully explaining how to manage table views is beyond the scope of a forum post. You should go look up a tutorial on the subject and follow it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!